# Влияение ссылок на продвижение сайта

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, продвижение

Насколько мне известно один из факторов ранжирования в поисковой системе являются ссылки. Актуальная ли эта информация? В качестве поисковой системы мне интересен только Google.

Если ссылки влияют на позицию в поисковой выдачи(как один из факторов), то я понимаю они могут влиять как положительно так и отрицательно. Тогда с этого следует вопрос, если на твой ресурс ссылаются сайты заспамленные они могут усугубить положение? Если да, то как сделать, чтобы гугл не обращал внимание.

Насчет ссылок, понятия не имею почему они ссылаются на мой ресурс. Покупкой ссылок не занимался.

Answer (score 2):

Да, ссылки влияют, качество донора и авторитетность.
Если только гугл то достаточно будет этого:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=ru
по ссылке детальная инструкция как создать список с игнором таких доноров.

Comment: _"Если в отношении вашего сайта были вручную приняты меры"_ - и часто такое происходит? И в каких случаях?

Comment: Вы вырываете из контекста. 
"если вы полагаете, что в отношении вашего сайта скоро будут приняты меры".
Автор не написал какие ссылки и сколько, задал вопрос можно ли. И по моему мнению, лучше не дожидаться момента, пока попадешь под какой-то фильтр.
+ ссылки имеют большой вес, их необходимо чистить и избавляться от старых покупных хвостов.

Comment: Но при этом чуть ниже они сами рекомендуют этим инструментом не пользоваться.

Comment: в старой версии search-consolи он был в свободном доступе ьез приписок и обьяснений. Возможно защита от дураков. 
Хотя если у вас есть другой вариант избавиться от мусора, который тянет сайт, я бы тоже почитала.Без сарказма.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, ссылки на твой сайт с других сайтов не могут ухудшать его рейтинг. Иначе это бы позволило конкурентам топить сайты размещая ссылки на них на сомнительных ресурсах.

А вот ссылки с твоего сайта на сомнительные, вероятно, скажутся отрицательно.